# Should I say "in the command line" or "on the command line"?

Tags: prepositions

Many IT workers use command-line utilities nowadays, and may of those utilities have "command-line arguments". I recently wrote the following sentence in an article:

> ... specify the option `<option>` **in** the command line.

On a later revision, I felt uneasy with the preposition in the above sentence. I have thought about these two alternatives.

> ... **on** the command line.
>
> ... **in** the command line **arguments**.

Questions:

- Is the first sentence grammatically correct? (with **in**) Do I need to replace it (to maintain proper English in my writings)?
- Are the alternatives I figured out correct and consistent in meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**on the command line** is the customary way to say it.

"... in the command line arguments" is too short / out of context to be able to judge it.

"**in** the command line" is grammatically correct, but is not used. It may be correct if you refer to the characters / symbols which form the command line, but without any meaning (as in command, option, value, argument, operator).

Example:

> I searched for [xyz] **in** the command line.
>
> I searched for the error **in** the command line.

Rarely, I encountered "**at** the command line", but I would feel comfortable using it. Or at least I cannot think of a context where this would be the better choice.

The following is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface):

> Options follow the command name **on** the command line, separated by spaces.

The following are taken from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html):

> - Program options specified **on** the command line follow these rules:
> - Option values that contain spaces must be quoted when given **on** the command line.
> - Multiple SQL statements may be passed in the option value **on** the command line, separated by semicolons: